# Optimizing a custom conv2d layer in tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to efficiently implement the following kind of conv2d layer. The current implementation I believe works but is very inefficient.

Input tensor of size

(batch_size x W x H x C_in)

Output tensor

(batch_size x W x H x C_out)

The layer takes two parameter, number of units (C_u), and a list of K conv kernels (known ahead of time). Each conv kernel is size (W,H,1,N) where N is the number of out channels (in channels being 1). Note, different kernels in the same like have different Ns!

First we apply a densely connected layer (trainable) transforming  input shape to

(batch_size x W x H x C_u)

Then, I want to apply each of the convolutional kernels to each of the channels.

This results in C_u x K x (batch_size x W x H x N)

I then want to take a max along N (so I get (batch_size x W x H x 1)) and concatenate everything to get

(batch_size x W x H x (C_u x K))

(so C_out = C_u x K)

Here is one way to implement this but training time is super slow and this does not play well with being put on the GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class fixedConvLayer(layers.Dense):

    def __init__(self, units, conv_kernels, **params):
        params['units']=units
        self.conv_kernels_numpy = conv_kernels
        super().__init__(**params)
        return

    def build(self, input_shape):

        super().build(input_shape)
        self.conv_kernels = [tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape(kernels,[3,3,1,-1]))                                                           
                                  for kernels in self.conv_kernels_numpy]

        return 

    def comp_filters(self,channel):

        return tf.concat([
                    tf.math.reduce_max(tf.nn.conv2d(channel,
                                      filter=kernel,
                                      strides=1,
                                      padding='SAME'),axis=3,keepdims=True)

                        for kernel in self.conv_kernels],axis=3)


    def call(self,inputs):

        #take from Dense definition and slightly modify
        inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs)
        rank = tf.rank(inputs)
        if rank != 4:
            assert 'Rank expected to be 4'


        # Broadcasting is required for the inputs.
        outputs = tf.tensordot(inputs, self.kernel, [[3], [0]])

        # Reshape the output back to the original ndim of the input.
        shape = inputs.shape.as_list()
        output_shape = shape[:-1] + [self.units]
        outputs.set_shape(output_shape)

        if self.use_bias:
            outputs = tf.nn.bias_add(outputs, self.bias)
        if self.activation is not None:
            outputs = self.activation(outputs)  

        #apply the conv filters
        channel_list = tf.split(outputs,num_or_size_splits= self.units,axis = -1)
        max_layers = tf.concat([self.comp_filters(channel) for channel in channel_list],axis=3)

        return max_layers
```

Comment: If N is fixed, you can take a look at `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d`. Each channel in the filters array is applied to each input channel.

Comment: “kernel size is (W,H,1,N)”. So is kernel size same as input features size? Or did I miss anything here?

Comment: Sorry, slightly imprecise notation. W and H are same (all kernels are 3x3), but N is different for each kernel in list of kernels. I think tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d is still useful since then I can do tf.split after convolution. So I will have K convolutions instead of K*C_u. I still have to apply conv2d using each of the K kernels. will play with this tomorrow and report back.

Comment: To clarify. I want to apply a set of kernels to each input channel. I then take a max output of each kernel. (So I have 8 kernels, 20 input channels, each kernel has N between 2 and 100+), final output size will be 160.